Why do bevels occasionally not work
I've noticed that sometimes bevels are flipped backwards and the only way I found to fix it is deleting faces/edges and rebuilding them with the remaining vertices. What causes this and is there a better fix?

Here's after a rebuild:


Always make sure that you've applied the scale to your object (Ctrl-A > Scale in Object mode) and also check the face normals by turning on Face Orientation on the Viewport Overlays menu before you try to bevel. - Not sure why you've added the node-editor tag to your question!
